# On .net Maui is there a way to navigate to a page midway through a function and pause that function till the form is closed?

Tags: android, .net, maui

I am converting a VB.NET(Windows CE) program to a android app using .net Maui. I have come across a line inside a function that I can't seem to find an alternative for on .net Maui.

```
If frmProd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
```

Is there a way for me to navigate to a page, pause the function, then once the page has been completed or canceled the function will continue again?

I have tried to show the page before the if statement but the function still continued to move despite passing the code for navigation.

Ideally, what I want it to do is to pause the function until the frmProd(page) has closed and I can get the value that's returned. Is there a way to do this on Maui?

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT I'm pretty sure, that this is not the best place to attack minor gramatical errors.

Answer (score 0):

I use this technique to solve this problem:

1. Declare a static function "Show" inside your page-to-wait class (TestPage) that is used to show the page-to-wait and wait for the response; something like this:

```
class TestPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<bool> TaskCompletionSource;

    public TestPage(TaskCompletionSource<bool> taskCompletionSource)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TaskCompletionSource = taskCompletionSource;
    }

    private async void ReturnToPreviousPage(bool result)
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync();

        TaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(result);
    }


    static public Task<bool> Show(Page page)
    {
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        page.Navigation.PushAsync(new TestPage(taskCompletionSource));

        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    // Other code here.
}
```

We call Show with the previous page instance as a parameter (ex: if (TestPage.Show(this)) ...) . That will create an instance of the page-to-wait and push it to the pages' stack.

2. Declare an async function (ReturnToPreviousPage) that takes the (Boolean here) value that you want to return (via the call to Show) to the previous page. Call this function in your code from the point you want to close the page-to-wait and return to previous page.
3. Check the result of Show, in your previous page, to decide what you have to do.

I hope this helps.